# Rander PDFAnnotation within new PDF

Tags: ios, swift, pdf, pdfkit, pdf-annotations

I followed this [article](https://medium.com/@rajejones/add-a-signature-to-pdf-using-pdfkit-with-swift-7f13f7faad3e)

to signature the PDF using PDFAnnotation

you can download the project using in the article [here](https://github.com/rajeejones/PDFSignature)

my problem is because it's PDFAnnotation if I download the pdf on my computer and then open it with Preview or any PDFviewer app
I can move the PDFAnnotation around the page!

and because my app is Client to Client

so Client 1 signature the PDF and then send it to Client 2
and also Client 2 signature the PDF

that why I need to render new pdf, that means the PDFAnnotation became within the PDF, not as PDFAnnotation

Also, you can download this [PDF](https://d3vv6lp55qjaqc.cloudfront.net/items/1D1o1V110n2H2u011H0M/test.pdf)

you will notice my problem and how the two PDFAnnotations can be moved around

Comment: I would suggest to use the isReadOnly property for the PDFAnnototation. Maybe this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49941644/ios-pdfkit-make-text-widget-pdfannotation-readonly

Comment: @Klinki I did try it ,
it kinda work inside the app , when I open the old PDF I can't move the PDFAnnotations but if I add another PDFAnnotations it also won't move after added it !
Also if I download the PDF it will still can move the PDFAnnotations
The Example PDF above is using same code on your link

Comment: HI, can you please share the latest and working code sample. I want to implement the same. If possible can share GitHub link with new/updated working code sample

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally find a solution!

Thanks to [tempire](https://gist.github.com/tempire) 
and his [code](https://gist.github.com/tempire/0bd8cb78290aa9bc6adf)

I did convert it to Swift 4.2

The idea here is not using PDFAnnotation!.

the Signature is an Image 
so when user save the PDF

I will use the signature Image
to create new PDF
and save it to same PDF file

to put your signature where you want it
you need the modify **X** and **Y**
`image.draw(in: CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 100, height: 100))`

```
   func drawOnPDF(path: String , signatureImage:UIImage) {

        // Get existing Pdf reference
    let pdf = CGPDFDocument(NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path))

        // Get page count of pdf, so we can loop through pages and draw them accordingly
    let pageCount = pdf?.numberOfPages


        // Write to file
        UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToFile(path, CGRect.zero, nil)

        // Write to data
        //var data = NSMutableData()
        //UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(data, CGRectZero, nil)

        for index in 1...pageCount! {

            let page =  pdf?.page(at: index)

            let pageFrame = page?.getBoxRect(.mediaBox)


            UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo(pageFrame!, nil)

            let ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

            // Draw existing page
            ctx!.saveGState()

            ctx!.scaleBy(x: 1, y: -1)

            ctx!.translateBy(x: 0, y: -pageFrame!.size.height)
            //CGContextTranslateCTM(ctx, 0, -pageFrame.size.height);
            ctx!.drawPDFPage(page!)
            ctx!.restoreGState()

            // Draw image on top of page
            let image = signatureImage
            image.draw(in: CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 100, height: 100))
            // Draw red box on top of page
            //UIColor.redColor().set()
            //UIRectFill(CGRectMake(20, 20, 100, 100));
        }


        UIGraphicsEndPDFContext()
    }
```

Comment: HI, can you please share the latest and working code sample. I want to implement the same. If possible can share GitHub link with new/updated working code sample

Comment: @NikitaPatil I had Demo project on github : https://github.com/X901/BurnImageToPDF